# How do I return head from structure

Tags: c

Code I have tried to return head:

```
node insert(node *head, int num){
  node *newnode;
  newnode=getnode();
  newnode->data=num;
  nednode->next=NULL;

  if(head==NULL){
     head=newnode;
     newnode->next = NULL;
  }
  head->next=newnode;
  return head;
}
```

After compiling, I am getting this error:

> "error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '*' token"

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't a complete code fragment and the types of the arguments aren't specified.

Comment: Probably your compiler is missing the declaration of `node`.

Comment: there also is a typo : change  `nednode->next=NULL;` to  `newnode->next=NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

Your function prototype seems incomplete:

```
node insert(*head,num)
```

Should be:

```
node insert(node *head, int num)
```

Comment: I forgot to write the datatype. It gives the same error even when the above  mentioned code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Your return value should probably be node*. Therefore it should be node* insert(node* head, int num);

Also you have a typo with newnode. I tried it and it worked for me after changing the return value.

Answer (score 0):

You code should like this.

change the nednode to newnode.

when you make the node connect with the link, you need to find the link's tail, and connect the new node to the tail.

And you should return the node* instead of node. So, change the func's return type to node*.

```
node* insert(node *head, int num){
  node *newnode;
  newnode=getnode();

  newnode->data=num;
  newnode->next=NULL;

  if(head==NULL){
     head=newnode;
  } else {
     node *p = head;
     while(p) {
       p = p->next;
     }
     p->next=newnode;
  }
  return head;
}
```